# Tableau - Data shown on map based on filter

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and I've tried Googling but can't find an answer on my issue (perhaps my keywords are wrong).

I have a set of data like this:
[image: Data]

I am able to create three individual worksheets to show on the map how many small, medium, big houses are there. It is linked to a second data set which pulls out the highest selling price for the house of the category and location.

I want to learn if it's possible to combine all three individual worksheets into one worksheet so that I can filter based on the size of the house (small, medium, big). If not, can I do the filtering on the dashboard instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape the data to make it flatter. Check this on [pivoting the data in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need!